# How to close JavaScript driven HTML Popup Box by clcking outside the Popup Box?

Tags: javascript, html

I make a JavaScript driven html popup box . The code work perfectly for me ,but now I need to press the close link to close the popup box. How can I modify the below code so that I can also close the popup box by clicking outside the popup box.

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if (e.style.display == 'block')
    e.style.display = 'none';
  else
    e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
#popupBoxOnePosition {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  display: none;
}
.popupBoxWrapper {
  width: 550px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: left;
}
.popupBoxContent {
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="popupBoxOnePosition">
  <div class="popupBoxWrapper">
    <div class="popupBoxContent">
      <h3>Popup Box 1</h3>
      <p>You are currently viewing popup box 1.</p>
      <p>Click <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('popupBoxOnePosition');">here</a> to close popup box one.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p>Click <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('popupBoxOnePosition');">here</a> to see popup box one.</p>
```

Please note I try below code but it doesn't work for me

```
 $('#popupBoxOnePosition').click(function(event){
                         event.stopPropagation();
 });
```

Comment: Bind an event to the `window` to close the popup onclick and then use `event.stopPropagation()` when clicking on the popup itself http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element

Comment: @YoavKadosh That code doesn't work for me that is why I ask this question

Comment: @Barmar That code doesn't work for me that is why I ask this question .Then how can it be a duplicate question.

Comment: Please show what you've tried. You show the code that stops propagation when clicking in the box, but where it the code that closes the box when you click somewhere else?

Comment: @GeordyJames your code is missing `$(window).click(function(){ /* Hide popup */ });`

Comment: @YoavKadosh I also try that but it cause my popup div tag to close automatically just by displaying it for blink of a sec.   $(window).click(function(){
                                 $("#popupBoxOnePosition").fadeOut();    
        });

Comment: In your case, since the popup box has a background that is covering the entire window, you have to bind the event to the popupbox wrapper rather than to the window. Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hfh8u00k/1/